# UpsertDE based on link click

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We would like to make an update to a data extension (more specifically, on a boolean field) based on whether a subscriber has clicked on a specific link (which suggests he/she is interested in an event we're organising). Is there a way or AMPscript code to achieve this via e.g. `UpsertDE` function? The fields in the mentioned DE are: `FederationID, EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, event_link_click` (boolean T/F).
Thanks

Comment: if it doesn't need to be immediate, you can gather this info via Query Activity looking at the _Click DataView. You just put it into an automation and set the frequency to whatever you need it.

Comment: Yes, it seems that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. AMPScript is ServerSide not ClientSide. Your option would be to create a cloudpage with either (InsertData or UpsertData) which you would link to inside your email with some parameters attached.

In the mail it would look like `Concat(RedirectTo(CloudpagesUrl(4711)),"?","attribute1=",@attribue1value,"&","attribute2=",@attribute2value)`

If the user clicks on that link, the functions will be executed on the server side and you then should redirect that user to the real target while some values will be written to a dataextension.

But this is not a good solution sometimes because mail clients might check links like this and instant redirects are often used in spam mails.

Comment: Ok, clear then. Although, I did test UpserDE with just the delivery factor and it updated a data extension field based on whether the email was sent to a person. of course, for this use case, this is useless. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Keep in mind, that executing Cloud Page impressions consumes supermessages, so it can (if the number of clicks is high and you are close to using all your supermessages) have an impact on your contract.

Comment: Do i understand that correctly @LukasLunow: When i would insert an unsubscribe link into my newsletter via cloudpagesurl it consumes a supermessage? Until now I only thought that would be applied when you use httpget to external content. Is this information posted somewhere or only in the head of experienced sfmc users.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick [Here is the definition](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/Agreements/product-specific-terms/marketing-cloud-super-message-bundles.pdf) of what consumes supermessages. A.O.: *1 CloudPages Impression consumes 1 Super Message*

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't need to be immediate, you can gather this info via Query Activity looking at the _Click DataView.

something like:

```
SELECT 
    c.FederationID
   ,c.EmailAddress
   ,c.FirstName
   ,c.LastName
   ,c.event_link_click
FROM (
       SELECT
               yde.FederationID
              ,yde.EmailAddress
              ,yde.FirstName
              ,yde.LastName
              ,true as 'event_link_click'
       FROM yourDE yde
       INNER JOIN _click cl ON yde.EmailAddress = cl.SubscriberKey
       WHERE cl.LinkName = "yourLinkName"
) c

/* Target: yourDE */
/* Action: update */
```

You just put it into an automation and set the frequency to whatever you need it to be. This will update the DE to set true for event_link_click for those that have clicked the link inside of the _click DV.

**Please note that I have not tested the query, this is more of just a sample to get you in the right direction and may not function as is.